# After setting a forwarding (routing) I cannot download files from servers

Tags: iptables, firewall, port-forwarding

I have found these codes on www to create a proxy for a software:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 2442 -j DNAT --to-destination some.ip.address:some.port
```

The 2442 is the port that I use to connect the software. The some.ip.address:some.port is destination's ip address and port. After setting these rules, I'm not able to download files from servers. How can I download files from servers with these rules applied?
PS: If I clear the iptables rules, it's fine. But after settings these rules It's not fine.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you attempt to achieve and what's not working.

Comment: Please explain what "proxy for a software", "I'm not able to download files from servers"  exactly mean.

Comment: the solution is to `clear the iptables rules` because then `it's fine` - explain why you think you need the rules in the first place, since clearly `it's fine` before you add some random rules for no reason

Comment: I am trying to make a proxy for a voice software which is TeamSpeak3. In TeamSpeak3, your IP is visible by all admins. I set those rules for hiding my IP with machine's IP. So I can't clear them.